# Remove sub directory from URL?

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I'd like to rewrite:

```
http://www.example.com/item.html/category/something/something2
```

To :

```
http://www.example.com/item/something/something2
```

Thus getting rid of "category" and ".html"

I have tried:

```
#rewrite to remove "category" and ".html"
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^item.html/category/
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ /item/category/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I'm using Magento. I do have other rules in place.  I've added what I've tried so far above.-thx

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the RewriteCond, just do the rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^item.html/category/(.*)$ /item/$1 [QSA,L]
```